# Conan to look for alternative libraries in requires

Tags: conan

I'm trying to create a conan package that has a dependency on a lib which have multiple possible implementations (for example openssl vs boringssl or OpenBlas vs BlasLapack)

The problem is that I do not understand how to write this in conan:

```
def requirements(self):
    self.requires("openssl/[>=x.y.z]")
    or # <= this is what I'm trying to do
    self.requires("boringssl/[>=x.y.z]")
```

Is it possible on the first place, And if yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, totally possible.

Actually we have real examples on official recipes [Conan Center Index](https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index).

Let's take a look in [usockets](https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/blob/689e2663fe41689259f61a5dbd3fe245e24c03b9/recipes/usockets/all/conanfile.py#L35) recipe:

```py
class ConanUSockets(ConanFile):
    ...
    options = {"with_ssl": [False, "openssl", "wolfssl"], ...}
    default_options = {"with_ssl": False}
    ...
    def requirements(self):
        if self.options.with_ssl == "openssl":
            self.requires("openssl/1.1.1g")
        elif self.options.with_ssl == "wolfssl":
            self.requires("wolfssl/4.4.0")
```

As you can see, we can use [options](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile/attributes.html#options) to determinate which requirement we want to use.

Thus, if we run `conan install usockets/<version> -o usockets:with_ssl=openssl` it will install OpenSSL as requirement.

Comment: Maybe I was not really clear, but I would like something that does it automatically (no need to pass an option). As a lib user, I don't care the version of the lib that is installed, and I would like conan to "guess" the best lib that also matches all other packages dependencies. Having to pass the option by hand would require me to resolve deps by hand to find out which one is accepted by all libs.

Comment: Conan won't guess it for you because it was designed to be explicit, the user must decide to avoid any possible unpredictable behavior. You are using version range which is not allowed for official recipes, since we want to guarantee the same dependency tree for each user. Also you can't check other dependencies on `requirements` because the dependencies graph is only built after that method (chicken egg problem) so you have to be explicit.

Comment: would it be possible then to have the option to automatically pick up the first one present if one or both is present in local cache? someting like `default_options = {"with_ssl": getFirstOf("openSsl", "borringSsl", false) }` ?

Comment: It's possible, but unusual. You would need to use Conan API to check your local cache first: https://github.com/conan-io/conan/blob/develop/conans/client/conan_api.py#L938. The API is not documented because it can breaks in terms of interface, but is pretty stable.